# How to remove Ext JS textfield displayed value?

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield, display

I've defined a Text field class for specialised usage and inherit a new class through the base one. The problem `textfield` keeps display value on it's own display field. Click the link please: [image: screen-shoot]

Here is some snippets. Could anyone explain the situation?

**Base Class**:

```
Ext.define('---.---.base.OoTextFld',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    xtype: 'ootextfld',
    grow: true,
    flex: 1,
    labelAlign:'right'
});
```

Inherited one which is used on Form:

```
Ext.define('---.---.base.InheritedFld',{
    extend:'---.----.base.OoTextFld',
    xtype:'inheritedfld',

    requires: [],

    name:---.---.inherited,
    fieldLabel: ---.inherited,
    afterLabelTextTpl: ---.Globals.required,
    bind: '{currRec.inherited}',
    grow: false
});
```

Comment: Does by any chance `currRec.inherited` holds a numeric value? I mean is the `inherited` field model [integer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Integer.html) or something similar?

Comment: @scebotari66 Nope. I've checked VM class and it's just mapping to DB.  As well have checked some other similar textfields but they works normal, doesn't display any value. For example on the same screen-shot you may see blue bordered textfield.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've provided. Can you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) showcasing the issue?

Comment: dear @scebotari66 you were right! It's occurs because of binding. I've mapped the model field as INT instead of STRING. Just changed model's field type. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the field is bound to an [integer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Integer.html) model field, so that when the a record is created with no value specified for this field, it automatically gets `0` as value.